# Оборот "все-таки"

Tags: пунктуация

Обособляется ли оборот "все-таки"? Например: "Это(,) все-таки(,) был ты?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все-таки не является вводным словом, поэтому запятыми не выделяется.

Answer (score 2):

Это не оборот, запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 2):

1. Всё-таки — союз, вносящий в семантику предложения значение "тем не менее, несмотря на что-н." (обычно в сочетании с союзами И, НО, А): Он некрасив, НО ВСЁ-ТАКИ мне нравится.
2. Всё-таки — усилительная частица: ВСЁ-ТАКИ он прав.
   ВСЁ-ТАКИ запятыми не выделяется: Это ВСЁ-ТАКИ был ты.